# CakePHP, file uploading, and inconsistent Auth

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an application built in CakePHP that is doing file uploads. For each file upload, I know the user's id, so I grab it from $this->Auth->user()

Now, what I have found is that when I am on the page, I will upload files while logged in but sometimes when I print_r the $this->Auth->user() it returns nothing back, and then the next time I try a file upload it will come back, all without e logging in or out. It seems extremely inconsistent, in that sometimes it is in there but other times it doesn't see it.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you require the Auth component throughout your app?

Comment: FIXED: security was set as "high" so it kept regenerating session IDs with my ajax calls, which was invalidating my sessions

Answer (score 0):

Why don't set a var in your app_controller to `$this->Auth->userModel` so it's accessible by the rest of the application.

In my app_controller I call the below in `before_filter` to set `$current_user`.

```
/**
 * Sets a value for current user $current_user.
 * @return boolean
 */
function __setCurrentUser() {
    $user = null;
    if ($user = $this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->set('current_user', $user[$this->Auth->userModel]);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my app, I can access `$current_user`'s id via `$current_user['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also always grab userinfo from the Session that is created by AuthComponent. If $this->Auth->user('id') is empty.. I'm wondering if there is actually a valid session! Are you sure you haven't been logged out in the meantime and the page isn't requiring a login for some reason?